# Adding dll as reference to a webservice in vb.net in visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, dll

We have created a dll,which was working fine for the vb.net application, when we referred by add reference in visual studio 2008.But I need to create a webservice which will invoke this dll and so the all operations of the dll can be invoked via webservice.This is the aim of the project.I have created the webservice in vs2008 and added the reference of the dll located in the local disk.But when I try to build the webservice it throws the following error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'COMWrapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Operating system:Windows 7 64 bit
Visual studio 2008
3.5 .Net Framework
Programming Language:Vb.net

Below is the webservice I Have created in VB

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class Service
     Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Dim oXRay As New COMClient.DLLCOMWrapper

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function TagDocWithRTFDoc(ByVal FileContent() As Byte, ByVal Ext As String) As String
        Dim result As String

        result = oXRay.TagDocWithRTFOutput(FileContent, Ext)
        Return result
    End Function

    <WebMethod()> _
   Public Function TagDocument(ByVal FileContent() As Byte, ByVal Ext As String) As String
        Dim result As String

        result = oXRay.TagDoc(FileContent, Ext)
        Return result
    End Function

    <WebMethod()> _
  Public Function ConvertDocument(ByVal FileContent() As Byte, ByVal Ext As String) As String
        Dim result As String

        result = oXRay.ConvertDoc(FileContent, Ext)
        Return result
    End Function

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Info() As String
        Dim result As String

        result = oXRay.GetLicenseInfo
        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Is this really a build error? Looks more like a runtime error. Do the x86/x64 configurations match?

Comment: If I build the project under x86 and refer the dll.Its building successfully.But when i run it shows following error at the browser  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F5796D23-C42B-4B98-A68C-0805289BCC55} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
   at Service..ctor() in c:\Users\venkat\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites1\App_Code\Service.cs:line 14

Comment: Are you running the service on the same machine as the original desktop application? Does the COM dll or one of its dependencies require registration?

Comment: Yes iam running service on the same machine.Yes of course One of its dependencies should be registered.And I have registered it already by regsvr32 ***.dll